# Depth Property in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

lets say i have this html code :

```
<div>
 <a>
    <span id="a"> </span>
 </a>
</div>
```

my question :

is there any js **property** which exposes element's depth ?

something like :

```
$("#a").prop ("depth") //3+3=6   +body+form+html   jquery selector is just for example.
```

*p.s. i know how to calc the depth. my question is about existing property.*

Comment: So you don't count `<html>` and `<body>` in the depth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any js property which exposes element's depth?

Not built-in, no. You could always make one using `defineGetter` and `defineSetter`.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
$('#a').first().parents().length
```

Edited as per **zzzzBov**'s comment.

Comment: too good to read my question  :  **js property **  && **p.s. i know how to calc the depth. my question is about existing property.**

Comment: ...for a single selection. For multiple items in the selection this will return the wrong value. You might want `$(..selector..).first().parents().length`.

Comment: Nitpicking: the OP seems to include the element itself as well in his definition of "depth".

Comment: That's true, you could add 1 to length to counteract that.

Comment: @pimvdb, `$(..selector..).first().parents().andSelf().length`

Comment: Or that. Wow zzzzBov, you're a jQuery ninja!